# What are the benefits of US citizenship for someone living elsewhere?

Tags: usa, passport, multiple-citizenship, benefits, renouncing-citizenship

If I have 3 passports (one from the US where I was born, one from the country where my family is from, and one from the country I currently live in). One of these non-US passports is that of an EU country. Both of the non-US passports are from places with high standards of living and less stressful lifestyles than US (according to me at least). I am not connected to the US, have no intention of living there ever, and I don't even intend to visit.

I want to renounce some day once I'm deeper into a career, regularly making a stable salary, and will be able to afford the ridiculous renunciation fee. But in the meantime, I want to take full advantage of the citizenship benefits. My mentality is that as long as I have this document and legal status which causes me such a headache, I may as well milk it for the benefits (whatever they may be). However, there don't seem to be many benefits except for things related to actually living, working, and voting in the US.

The only things I can think of are:

- Using my American passport to sign up for freelance work on Upwork which has a reserved marketplace for US based users (I will do this, but only for a part time side job while I'm still growing professionally)
- Becoming a "digital nomad" and filing my taxes under Foreign Earned Income Exclusion and effectively paying nothing (sounds nice but I don't want to leave my country, I love my life here)
- Traveling visa-free to Mongolia (I will do this, but this is kind of a one time thing)
- Sign up for US banking and credit cards (which I am against because they sell your data and try to put you in debt)
- Being rescued by Seal Team 6 if I get kidnapped by terrorists (which I really highly doubt will happen)

What else is there? What would you do if you were me?

Comment: If you are eligible to vote in US elections, please do (on the assumption that you will do a better job than many US residents).

Comment: How is that legal status you're in causing you such a headache ? Paying the  renunciation fee ($2K) might be money well spent if your head is aching too much.

Comment: One recent benefit is eligibility for the 2020 and 2021 US stimulus payments.